# Why isn't my implementation of a virtual function being called in this case?

Tags: c++, c++14, virtual-functions

I have access to an interface, that implements the virtual method `iObjectManager::getTile(const Course::ObjectId &id) = 0`. I've reimplemented said method in an inherited `class ObjectManager:public Course::iObjectManager` as follows:

```
std::shared_ptr<Course::TileBase> getTile(const Course::ObjectId &id) override;

std::shared_ptr<Course::TileBase> ObjectManager::getTile(const Course::ObjectId &id)
{
  qDebug() << "Looking for tile based on ID...\n";
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < getMapSize(); i++) {
    for (unsigned j = 0; j < getMapSize(); j++) {
      std::shared_ptr<BoardPiece> tile = getGameMap().at(i).at(j);
      if (tile->ID == id) {
        qDebug() << "Tile found.\n";
        return std::move(tile);
      }
    }
  }
  qDebug() << "No tile with given index...\n";
  return nullptr;
}
```

The issue arises, when the course side code calls `getTile`: nothing happens. The calls to `qDebug` are not made and nothing is printed. Why would the function fail to get called (or the one lacking an implementation get called) even though I've implemented the function properly (I think)?

The functio is called as follows:

```
tile = lockObjectManager()->getTile(ID);
```

where `lockObjectManager`  is defined as

```
std::shared_ptr<iObjectManager> GameObject::lockObjectManager() const
{
    std::shared_ptr<iObjectManager> handler = OBJECTMANAGER.lock();
    Q_ASSERT(handler);
    return handler;
}
```

### Edit

I've just discovered, that my `ObjectManager` is destroyed right after its initialization. This is weird, as I have it set as a member of my `MainWindow` right at the start of its construction, but it is also given to my `GameEventHandler` as an initialization parameter, and the `gameEventHandler` does not die either (based on my `qDebug`ging):

```
GOManager_ = std::make_shared<ObjectManager>(playerAges_);
GEHandler_ = std::make_shared<GameEventHandler>(GOManager_);
```

Either the main window of the eventhandler (or both) should be keeping the objectmanager alive, but they are not... Is this because I've not provided an assignment operator, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8872074/why-is-this-destructor-being-called-immediately-after-creation)?

Comment: There's not enough context to say anything, so please try to create a [mcve] to show us. Perhaps refresh about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: It doesn't look like you call getTile at all, in this code. I'm assuming wherever you do call it, use used a syntax that specifies which class to call it on, rather than virtual lookup.

Comment: Double check that in the base class, the `getTile()` method has the `virtual` keyword in its declaration, and that its signature matches the signature of your subclass-method *exactly* (including with respect to the presence/absence of a `const` keyword at the end of the signature)

Comment: "The calls to qDebug are not made and nothing is printed" - are you sure the `qDebug` output is going where you expect it to? Your IDE may be intercepting it, it may have been redirected to a file, the output may be going to `std::cerr` and you only check `std::cout` (or vice versa). Lots of things could be happening that don't all mean that the code is not running.

Comment: What object are you calling `getTile` on?  Could you be [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) your original object?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner The `virtual` keyword is there, and there is no `const` at the end of the signature. To my eyes, the declarations are exactly the same, no includign the class specifier (`iObjectManager` vs `ObjectManager`).

Comment: Could you add your declaration of `tile` and `lockObjectManager` along with whatever value you set them to?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure OBJECTMANAGER.lock() is returning an instance of the derived ObjectManager class. If it is returning iObjectManager(), it will call its base version of getTile(), not the overloaded one.

Comment: This might be it. I've just discovered, that my Objectmanager is destroiyed right after its initialization. For some reason my main window is not keeping it alive, even though the `ObjectManager` is set as its member variable right at the initialization of said window.